# Query to find students attending same college using Graphi API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way I can find out all students(fb users) attending my university currently ?
I do not want to go with FQL as its gonna be decommissioned soon. I just want to use Graph API

Comment: That's not possible via the Graph API afaik.

Comment: @Tobi - thanks for the answer Tobi. What would the FQL query look like if way to go is FQL ?

Comment: With FQL it also doesn't seem to be possible after a quick research. The only indexable field of the `user` table is `uid`, but you want to search for "all students", so from my point of view this isn't working.

Comment: Ok, also when I query user using graph API for his groups or friends, I do not get the any response though I can see his groups n friends after directly opening.his profile. Not sure what is going wrong.